# ValueError: You must specify a period or x must be a pandas object with a DatetimeIndex with a freq not set to None - decompose() time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am using Python3 and have a time series daily data as follows:

[image]

The time series starts on 2018-01-02 and ends on 2018-12-11 (having 318 days of values).

The goal is to perform basic time series analysis by decomposing the observations using 'seasonal_decompose()' from 'statsmodels.tsa.seasonal'. The code I am using is:

```
data = pd.read_csv("Time_Series.csv", parse_dates = ['dates'], index_col = 'dates')
data.sort_index(inplace = True)

# Multiplicative decomposition-
result_mul = seasonal_decompose(data['num_incidents_resolved'], model = 'multiplicative', extrapolate_trend = 'freq')
```

This gives the error:

> ValueError: You must specify a period or x must be a pandas object
> with a DatetimeIndex with a

If I try to set the time window using 'period' parameter as follows-

result_mul = seasonal_decompose(data['num_incidents_resolved'], model = 'multiplicative', period = 318)

The error I get is:

> ValueError: x must have 2 complete cycles requires 636 observations. x
> only has 318 observation(s)

Help?

freq not set to None

Comment: Here, you gave the length of your series, not its period. The period could be a week, a month, a quarter ...